# Do links to my site in www.mysite.blogspot.com point back to my site or blogger?

Tags: seo, blog, backlinks, blogger

I've recently started a website and of course I'm trying to build backlinks.  I've started a blogger blog as one way to do this yet I'm continually hounded by sales calls that tell me if I post a link to my site in a `.blogspot.com` blog it doesnt actually point to my site and therefore get no credit for the link.  I can't seem to find this information on my own so I'm not sure if it's "sales people crap" or the truth.

Am I wasting my time trying to build links this way? Do I really need another domain strictly for blogging or do the links in my blogger blog actually help my site?

Answer (score 3):

Mistake 1. Making your own backlinks

Mistake 2. Reading on how to make your own back links

Mistake 3. The wiliness to create content on a 2nd site for the primary of objective of feeding back to your money site.

In this day and age it is pretty much pointless to spend time building links on Web2.0 platforms such as Blogger. The time that goes into creating these links and content is time wasted on creating content on your actual site that will not only be more viable as a long term strat, Google will love you for it and so will your visitors.

But to answer your question, Yes the back links from Blogger do work, but unless you have the following blogger site its pointless:

1. A aged blogger site with its own backlinks.
2. A blogger site that is well developed, on topic to your own niche. A backlink is only as good as the site its coming from.

Links from aged sites are more effective, also the more content and authority they have the better the effect, but Google doesn't want you to manipulate the search results which could come to haunt you. Additionally to make it even worth while you'd have to build lots of pages on the Blogger site, simply creating one or two pages and then linking back to your money site will hardly be noticeable in the search results, since back linking has a 100 of factors of its own.

Spend ever free moment you have on your site and look at ways you can drive traffic to your site, Baiting works wonders, look up that... Creating rich content that will drive traffic and naturally gain backlinks to your site.

Answer (score 2):

As long as those links are not `nofollow` technically they help your site. However, the value of those links are going to be very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very, very small. That blogspot site will have few, if any, incomming links, and overall it will have little strength from which to prop up your other site. Your return on investment (time) will be so small that it will essentially be a waste of time.

My advice, don't bother doing this.

Comment: LOL John! BEAT ME too it ;)

Comment: Just by a hair! But I think you're answer is better so technically you win. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to work at your blog for a while (minimum 6 months) and if you have things to say, then eventually those backlinks will have some value.    It will take time, and you will need to have good quality unique content on the blog.   But it will pay off.

In the shorter term, you could look at commenting on other blogs in your niche.   Not spam comments ("nice blog") and lot with backlinks to your site (more spam).    Just genunine, honest comments that contribute to the conversation.   Over time, this will build interest in your profile, and thus your blog, which will eventually lead to more worthy backlinks to your website.

Also, if any sales-guy tells you that links in blogspot all point back to blogger not to your site - end the conversation immediately because s/he doesn't know anything about the topic.